# Adding titles to ggplots created by lapply

Tags: r, ggplot2, lapply

How can I add titles based off the a list of variables? The code below works to produce the 10 plots, but there are no titles. I would like the titles to reflect the variables listed inthe dfList.

```
dfList<-list(s$Basioccipital,s$Basisphenoid,s$Interparietal,s$L_Frontal,s$L_LateralOccipital,s$L_Nasal,s$L_Parietal,s$L_SquamousTemporal,s$Presphenoid,s$SquamousOccipital)


lapply(dfList, function (x){
  ggplot(data=x,aes(x=Genotype2, y=Volume))+
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=factor(Genotype2))) + ggtitle(dfList[i])
})
```

Comment: You should consider including a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help folks help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't test this as you don't include any data, but here's a potential solution...

```
dfList<-list("Basioccipital", "Basisphenoid", "Interparietal",
             "L_Frontal", "L_LateralOccipital", "L_Nasal", "L_Parietal", 
             "L_SquamousTemporal", "Presphenoid", "SquamousOccipital")


lapply(dfList, function (x){
  ggplot(data=s[[x]],aes(x=Genotype2, y=Volume))+
    geom_boxplot(aes(fill=factor(Genotype2))) + ggtitle(x)
})
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code in place of your current ggtitle:

```
 ggtitle(names(dfList[i]))
```